# Javascript Reorganizing Shuffled Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am fairly new to Javascript. Unfortunately, there is a hard restriction in that I have to use it for this task. That being said, I would appreciate any help or guidance.

I have an array of names. For the sake of a simple example, see below:

`var names  = ['Tyrone', 'Jamal', 'Brett', 'Todd', 'Latoya', 'Tamika', 'Anne', 'Meredith'];`

I also can separate this array and create two distinct arrays based on gender:

`var mens_names = ['Tyrone', 'Jamal', 'Brett', 'Todd'];`

`var womens_names = ['Latoya', 'Tamika', 'Anne', 'Meredith']`

What I am currently trying to do is shuffle the array `names` and then reorganize the positioning of the elements such that there are always two names with the same gender next to each other. Continuing with the above example:

```
// Define shuffle function //

function shuffle(array){
  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;
  while (0 !== currentIndex){
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }
  return array;
}


names = shuffle(names); // Shuffle array of names
```

Let us say the output of the shuffled array is:

```
names = ['Brett','Jamal', 'Latoya', 'Todd', 'Tyrone', 'Tamika', 'Meredith', 'Anne' ]
```

What I am trying to do is now reorganize this array such that the same gender names are next to each other with regards to element positioning within the array. Hence, if I hypothetically had a function to do this then it would look something like this:

```
paired_names = ['Brett', 'Jamal', 'Latoya', 'Tamika', 'Todd', 'Tyrone', 'Meredith', 'Anne']
```

So the functionality that I am trying to achieve here is that the function looks at the first element in the shuffled `names` array and `push()` it into a new array `paired_names` then `pop()` it from `names` (so `paired_names` starts out empty, hence, `paired_names = [])` then conditional on the name being a male name the function will search for the next male name and `push()` it into the new array. It does this then iteratively until `names` is empty. So following the above example, the first iteration should produce an outcome such that:

```
names = ['Latoya', 'Todd', 'Tyrone', 'Tamika', 'Meredith', 'Anne']
```

and

```
paired_names = ['Brett', 'Jamal']
```

Second iteration:

```
names = ['Todd', 'Tyrone', 'Anne', 'Meredith']
```

and

```
paired_names = ['Brett', 'Jamal', 'Latoya', 'Tamika']
```

and so on.... until `names = []`

I tried this myself doing object pairs with `{}`. See below at my rough sketch attempt. The syntax is wrong, probably considering it did not run correctly, but hopefully, it will suffice in terms of mechanically showing what I am trying to obtain.

```
var names = ['Tyrone', 'Jamal', 'Brett', 'Todd' 'Latoya', 'Tamika', 'Anne', 'Meredith'];
var mens_names = ['Tyrone', 'Jamal', 'Brett', 'Todd'];
var womens_names = ['Latoya', 'Tamika', 'Anne', 'Meredith'];

function get_pairs(names) {

  names = shuffle(names);

  let pairs = [];
  while (names.length > 0) {
    let pair = {name_one: names.pop, name_two: names.pop };
    pairs.push(pair);
  }

  return pairs;
}

let guys = get_pairs(womens_names);
let girls = get_pairs(mens_names);

let combined = girls.concat(guys);

combined = shuffle(combined);

//To use

for (let i = 0; i < combined.length; i++) {
  let name_pairs = combined.pop();

  let name_one = name_pairs.name_one;
  let name_two = name_pairs.name_two;
}
```

Am I on the right track? Is there a better way? Any help would be great!

Comment: You're making this much more complicated than it needs to be. Shuffle the two arrays of male and female names. Then alternate taking two elements from each of them into the result.

Comment: Ah, okay I will try that thank you! :D

Comment: Do you need 2 functions for this or you can use 1 function that shuffle and gives you shuffled array with genders next to each other?

Comment: I am not sure. Whichever is computationally more feasible. As Barmar noted above, that would be only 1 function, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write function to get array in random order for given array (eg. `randomOrder`)

Get the random order of `mens_names` and `womens_names`.

Go over for loop (with length of men or women names array), push 2 consecutive elements from both arrays in result array. (Thanks @Barmar)

```js
const mens_names = ["Tyrone", "Jamal", "Brett", "Todd"];
const womens_names = ["Latoya", "Tamika", "Anne", "Meredith"];

const randomOrder = arr => {
  const myRandom = () => Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) % arr.length);
  const output = [];
  arr.forEach(x => {
    let index = myRandom();
    while (output.includes(arr[index])) {
      index = myRandom();
    }
    output.push(arr[index]);
  });
  return output;
};

const res = [];
const mens_ord = randomOrder(mens_names); 
const woms_ord = randomOrder(womens_names);

for (let i = 0; i < mens_names.length; i = i + 2) {
  res.push(mens_ord[i], mens_ord[i + 1]);
  res.push(woms_ord[i], woms_ord[i + 1]);
}




// UPDATE
// Scenario 1: Randomize the Male/Female, But at time consecutive same gender only 2 names.

if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
  res.reverse();
}

console.log(res);

// Scenario 2: Randomize, But it is ok to have eg. MMFFFFMM (4 names same gender)
// Change above for loop to
/* 
for (let i = 0; i < mens_names.length; i = i + 2) {
  const temp_arr = [mens_ord[i], mens_ord[i + 1]),woms_ord[i], woms_ord[i + 1]];
  if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
    temp_arr.reverse();
  }
  res.push(...temp_arr);
}

console.log(res);
*/
```

Comment: Close, the randomization part is correct, but inside the for loop the order in which it pushes elements from ```mens_ord``` and ```woms_ord``` is deterministic. It is always male pair then female pair. I think it needs to be restructured to random. Not sure how to do this.

Comment: @NicholasLacourse, Ah ok. I just updated the answer with 2 possible scenarios. Hope that helps.

Comment: It does, thank you! Learning how many ways you can actually do it is always fun!

Answer (score 0):

You can use for

```js
var names = ['Tyrone', 'Jamal', 'Brett', 'Todd', 'Latoya', 'Tamika', 'Anne', 'Meredith'];
var mens_names = ['Tyrone', 'Jamal', 'Brett', 'Todd'];
var womens_names = ['Latoya', 'Tamika', 'Anne', 'Meredith'];
let i = 1
let pared = []
for (let n = 0; n < names.length / 2; n += 2) {
  i = 1 + n
  pared = [...pared, mens_names[n], mens_names[i], womens_names[n], womens_names[i]]
}
console.log(pared)
```

you can also use a `filter` to get rid of empty space if it occurs

Comment: The issue here is that the array needs to be random each time it is run. This produces the same array each time.  Also, even if it is random the male names will always be the first pair, right?

Answer (score 0):

I tried again and in that time massive random each time it run

```
  function getRandomInRange(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

var names = ['Tyrone', 'Jamal', 'Brett', 'Todd', 'Latoya', 'Tamika', 'Anne', 'Meredith'];
var mens_names = ['Tyrone', 'Jamal', 'Brett', 'Todd'];
var womens_names = ['Latoya', 'Tamika', 'Anne', 'Meredith'];
let i = 1
let pared = []
for (let n = 0; n < names.length / 2; n += 2) {

 let a = getRandomInRange(0, mens_names.length-1)
 pared = [...pared, mens_names[a]]
 mens_names =  mens_names.filter((it, ind)=> ind!==a)

 let c = getRandomInRange(0, mens_names.length-1)
  pared = [...pared, mens_names[c]]
  mens_names = mens_names.filter((it, ind)=> ind!==c)

  let b = getRandomInRange(0, womens_names.length-1)
  pared = [...pared, womens_names[b] ]
  womens_names =  womens_names.filter((it, ind)=> ind!==b)

 let e = getRandomInRange(0, womens_names.length-1)
 pared = [...pared, womens_names[e] ]
 womens_names = womens_names.filter((it, ind)=> ind!==e)

}
console.log(pared)
```

Comment: Ah much better! Thank you so much @Nikita!